# No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a routing error when I browse to my index page. I setup some straightforward stuff, model has `:title (string)` and `:content(text)`.

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing all notes</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
  <p><%= post.content %></p>
  <hr/>
<% end %>
<small><%= link_to "Add New Note", new_post_path %></small>
<small><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %></small>
```

**post_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
   @posts = Post.all
end

def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
def new
   @post.new
end

def create
   @post = Post.new(params[:post])

   if @post.save
       redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your Note was Saved!"
   else
       render "new"
   end
end

def edit
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])

   if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
       redirect_to posts_path
   else
       render "edit"
   end
end
```

When I browse to the app on `:3000/posts`, I receive the error:

> No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}

My routes.rb looks like usual.

**routes.rb**

```
NotePad::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :posts
```

Any help would be very useful.

Comment: Only thing i see is in `new`: `@post.new` should be `@post = Post.new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error on your index.html.erb file. The correct syntax is:

```
<h1>Listing all notes</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h2><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h2>
  <p><%= post.content %></p>
  <hr/>
<% end %>
<small><%= link_to "Add New Note", new_post_path %></small>
```

And the edit link is wrong too

Comment: Thanks Sailor, that worked. How do you mean there's a problem on the Edit field? I have tried the below

    <small><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %></small>
and
    <small><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %></small>

Comment: You have to put your edit link into the block and call `link_to 'edit', edit_post_path(post)`

Answer (score 3):

This will not solve your problem but it can help you:

```
$ rake routes
```

This will show you all routes on your app.